# Help page for search is missing

Tags: bug, status-completed

It looks like search is available in the current API but there is no help page for it.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/search?intitle=test

Answer (score 2):

Now, I could able see search on help page. Fixed!

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=search